# Cofiguration Rmetrics with Rcov in hudson error

Tags: hudson, rcov

When I attempt to save a job that runs code coverage tests and is configured to publish an rcov report I get the error message listed below and the changes I made aren't saved. This problem cropped up with Hudson version 1.362 and exists in 1.363. If I uncheck the "Publish coverage report" checkbox the job can be saved.

Status Code: 500
Exception:
Stacktrace:

java.lang.InstantiationError: hudson.plugins.rubyMetrics.rcov.model.MetricTarget
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindParametersToList(RequestImpl.java:271)
at hudson.plugins.rubyMetrics.rcov.RcovPublisher$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(RcovPublisher.java:143)
at hudson.plugins.rubyMetrics.rcov.RcovPublisher$DescriptorImpl.newInstance(RcovPublisher.java:104)
at hudson.util.DescribableList.rebuild(DescribableList.java:147)
at hudson.model.Project.submit(Project.java:198)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleProject.submit(FreeStyleProject.java:97)
at hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:1050)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:555)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:235)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:116)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:57)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:75)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:30)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:525)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:181)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:30)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:525)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:441)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:123)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:249)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:335)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:378)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:94)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:244)
at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Does anyone have a good solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See Hudson [Bugreport 6808](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6808)